Can I come back to my country (India) with less than 6 months validity on my passport from Vietnam through Malaysia?
Can I come back to my country (India) with a less than 6 months validity on my passport from Vietnam through Malaysia?

If you are visiting Malaysia too, that may be different from when you are only in transit, and that will depend on whether the transit is land-side or air-side.

The answer may also depend upon the identity of the airline(s) involved, the identity of the Malaysian airport, and the length of time between the flight to Malaysia and the flight from Malaysia.
